# AVR USB to Serial Converter; Quick Question

Tags: usb, avr, serial, converter, zener

I have a TI86 calculator that I've had for over 7 years now. Well I'm letting a lady friend on mine borrow it, and I was going to load it up with some apps for her. And the tradeoff is happening this weekend. So I figured, "hey, let's just build a cable really quick". Well I got going down the rabbit hole and since I don't have a serial or parallel port anymore, I'd need a converter.

So I found an AVR USB to Serial converter schematic (which I'm sure ya'll are really familiar with) here:[image: AVR USB to Serial Converter]

Couple things:
1. I don't have a straight ATMega8\48\88 around. I only have the 48A-MU\PU, 88A-MU\PU, and the 324P-20PU (which is my favorite) and 328P-PU (Second favorite) immediately available. Without sounding too dumb, am I correct in assuming with the exception of the 324P, the other AVR's I have are compatible? I've used a 328P before for some stuff for the 88 since according to the datasheet it's more or less the same chip, just different grades of it.
2. I only have a 16 Mhz and 20 Mhz crystal. Would it be disastrous if I used those instead, or do I need to modify the code to be safe?

And then last question on this schematic:
[image: TI Serial Link]

3. If I had 3.6V and 5.1V Zeners, could I make them work? Is there an alternative if not? Zeners aren't something I use, so they're also a mystery to me sometimes too.

So like I said, silly questions. But I'd rather ask before I go wasting my chips and parts, you know?

Gracias, my friends.

Comment: The clock for USB needs to be pretty accurate and the crystal frequency has to match the code closely. V-USB does have an all software implementation though where the internal RC oscillator is calibrated to 16.5 MHz. For V-USB to work you need the 64 MHz PLL in the AVR, a device without PLL won't work. Beware that the signals on the USB data lines are 3.5V or so, certainly not 5V.

Comment: Oh that makes much more sense why the Zeners are 3.6. You can tell how much I work with USB ;) So then I can't use a prescaler in code to set the frequency at 12mhz if I'm using like a 16mhz crystal? I've read about using flip flops as dividers. I've also discovered how to create a clock with a second AVR. I'd assume I could output a 12mhz signal on one of the pins with a simple Do\Loop?

Comment: When using V-USB I'd opt for the software calibrated internal RC oscillator. AVR's are too slow to generate a 12 MHz output, as you'd need at least a 24 MHz system clock for that. AVRs are limited to 20 MHz system clock.

Comment: You mean 20mhz max? I'm aware of that bit. But it looks like I'll be working with V-USB for this project. Any other pointers to help? Schematics? I'm very visual

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, the various atmega parts are likely to be compatible for this particular application. V-USB does not use many internal resources.
2. V-USB supports both 16MHz and 20MHz crystals. You will have to modify the circuit.
3. Are you going to use this circuit with AVR? Because you AVR circuit produces TTL-level serial data (0/5v), while "The Serial Link" circuit expects RS232-level serial data (-12/+12V). The serial link circuit uses all the zeners and resistors to convert RS232-level to a TTL-level in a special way.

So the two schematics you have posted are not compatible, unless you add another level shifter / converter (MAX232) so you can go TTL->RS232->TTL, which seems silly to me.

Comment: So I'd be far better off just using a USB-Serial converter IC?

Comment: In schematics #1, AVR becomes USB-Serial converter _IC_, so a different usb-serial IC will not help. You can use USB-Serial converter "dongle" (which has 2 ICs inside: converter IC + level shifter) with schematics #2.

Comment: But if I was to do it myself, no dongle, I need a level shifter? Like a logic lever shifter?

Comment: You will need a RS232 level shifter. Here is a common example: http://www.dragons-lair-project.com/tech/images/EuroDL/serialinterface.jpg (avr connects to the left, adapter converts on the right). It uses MAX232, and does not do RTS/DSR lines. Your schematics will need biogger converter chip like MAX236.

Comment: My my.... I'd just probably be better off buying the USB cable. Didn't think it was so complex to be honest.